# opengles not being rendered on instant app on some devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, google-play-services, rendering, android-instant-apps

I wrote an opengl game but it is not being rendered on some android versions when running as instant app, however it works on all android versions when running as normal app, the same app bundle is used for both the instant and normal app, here is the relevant log info:

```
2019-05-17 16:54:25.219 10802-10909/? W/aiagpu: [0517/155425:WARNING:features.cc(44)] feature NoOpReleaseOrDestroySurface: 0
2019-05-17 16:54:25.232 10802-10909/? W/aiagpu: [0517/155425:WARNING:features.cc(44)] feature NoOpReleaseOrDestroySurface: 0
2019-05-17 16:54:41.831 10802-10909/? W/aiagpu: [0517/155441:WARNING:features.cc(44)] feature EnableServiceSideGlError: 0
2019-05-17 16:54:41.833 10802-10909/? W/aiagpu: [0517/155441:WARNING:features.cc(44)] feature IgnoreDrawArraysCall: 0
2019-05-17 16:54:41.833 10802-10909/? W/aiagpu: [0517/155441:WARNING:features.cc(44)] feature CheckVertexAttribMemoryBoundary: 0
2019-05-17 16:54:41.836 10802-10909/? E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
```

Comment: Not sure how we're supposed to provide advice when you've given us nothing to explain what your application actually does. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex and improve your question.

Comment: I am saying that the issue is on the instant app api not on my app

Comment: OpenGL ES is supported for instant apps, so pretty sure the issue is going to be related to how your application is using the API on the specific devices it has problems with. Given you've provided zero details about either, how can we help?

Comment: Why the same apk work perfectly on the same device when it is installed? Please read the question I am saying that on the devices that the instant app doenst work, the normal apk works, and botb apks are exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132952558 is you?

Quoting the answer here so it helps others as well:

> OpenGL ES 1.0 is only partially supported, we do not recommend you to
> use this.
>
> OpenGL ES 2.0 is fully supported for Instant Apps.
>
> Additionally, OpenGL ES 3.0 is not supported on pre-O Instant Apps.
>
> This was previously documented somewhere, but not anymore, so we’re
> working on getting these details back in.